# CSRF token doesn't work (yii2) with https

Tags: yii2

I test app on local is ok. I deploy to server with `https` domain. When i submit form then show 400 Error: Bad Request (#400): Unable to verify your data submission.

And have problem with `Https`, how can i fix it

Comment: i turn off $enableCsrfValidation = false and it's work. Now i want user csrf to verify data.

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you have got non-secure cookies blocked when sending over https. Try this in configuration:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        // ...
        'request' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Request',
            'csrfCookie' => [
                'httpOnly' => true,
                'secure' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: yes, i try set $enableCsrfValidation to true, and set as you say, so it's not work. i will test again.

Comment: Edit your question with the code of form you are using along with controller's action that handles it.

Comment: i try access again, so now it's work perfect, thank you